# How add automatic functionality to this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm happy with how this slideshow works, but I would like it to be automatic after 3 seconds in the event the user doesn't manually advance the slide.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove("active");
    
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
};
```

Comment: You can explore setInterval and clearInterval function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setInverval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to automatically execute `plusSlides` at regular intervals. If the user interacts manually, you can use [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearInterval.asp) to stop the automatic advancement of slides.

```js
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      plusSlides(1)
  }, 3000);
```

This would advance the slide by one every 3000ms (3 seconds). If you now want to disable the automatic advancement (maybe because a user interacted with something) you can use:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Thanks @Felix I appreciate that, are you able to show me an example of how it would work?

Comment: @soe123 I added an example to my original reply.